# Larry and the fanboys

Tags: punctuation, commas

In the Penguin guide to punctuation Larry Trasks claims that a joining comma must be followed by *and*, *or*, *but*, *yet* or *while*.

However, I was under the impression that a joining comma should be followed by one of the FANBOYS (*for*, *and*, *not*, *but*,  *or*, *yet* and *so*).

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: What’s a joining comma?

Comment: You have to be a Larry Trask fanboi to know his system & explain it all. It's all available on the web. I've looked at it, & as impressive as his work is, it's just another way of looking at the same old stuff we've had to deal with in English grammar classes for the past two hundred years. I found his comma types contradictory at worst & a bit unclear at best. I'd suggest ignoring the terminology for the simple reason that a comma is a comma is a comma. _Why is the comma there?_ That explains its function in the sentence. _Is it necessary?_ You'll find no "joiner" tattoo on any comma.

Comment: @tchrist A joining comma is used to join two complete clauses. It is followed by a coordinating conjunction. For example: *I am going away, and I may not come back.*

Comment: @Bill Franke "I found his comma types contradictory at worst." In what way?

Comment: @TheFrog: The so-called "joining comma". But I guess when one attempts to clean out the Augean stables, one will always miss a few horse apples. That "joining comma" in your example is strictly optional in 21st-century English. The conjunction joins the two sentences. Therefore, it's a useless comma. See what I mean?

Comment: @tchrist Good & innocent q. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&q=cache:xCp16M_pBsQJ:http://www.ucl.ac.uk/english/Punctuation_answers%2Bdefine+%22joining+comma%22&gbv=2&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3...376240.380902.0.381117.22.22.0.0.0.0.303.2534.10j10j1j1.22.0...0.0...1c.1.GHbfdhKMgOU&ct=clnk

Comment: @tchrist And, http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node11.html#SECTION00042000000000000000

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95328/14666

Comment: @Bill Franke: Trask, himself, indicates this comma may be removed, in particular if the first clause is short. However, it is useful to distinguish between different usages of *and*. A sentence starting with *Jane liked Peter and Paul...* (OK, this is a simplistic example) requires that you read further to understand whether Paul is a complement of the first clause or the subject of a new clause. Often in English you have to reread from the start of the sentence because you did not make the correct structural assumption at the start. That is a reason why this kind of punctuation is useful IMO.

Comment: @TheFrog: I love commas for just the reason you mention. Many claim that I overuse them. I love grammar. And I love having cognitive boxes to stick stuff like commas into. My criteria for labeling, however, are slightly different from Trask's in some cases. I prefer to identify by analyzing function & whether it works: show me, then I'll tell you what you are, case by case. For me, commas always separate, even when they're wedges for inserts. A conjunction joins, but a comma's not a conjunction. But that's an overgeneralization. His work is impressive, but _joining comma_'s not useful to me.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy comes from nothing more than the incompleteness of each set of words. Notice that the two sets of words overlap a good deal, and that neither one *excludes* the other, nor do they exclude any other possibilities.

And let's not forget that a fundamental use of the comma is to indicate a pause, especially when the pause would be utilized if the words were spoken. (Which means that The Frog's example of a joining comma is not necessarily useless, but yes, it's optional.)