# What is this comma called?

Tags: grammar, commas, conjunctions

> A room furnished comfortably and tastefully, but not extravagantly.

Is there any special name for this comma before 'but' and will the sentence work if we don't use it?

Comment: It's optional. If you would pause before "but" then include the comma - it might depend how you were bracketing it, i.e. "(comfortably and tastefully) but not extravagantly" or "comfortably and (tastefully but not extravagantly)". Is there more likely to be a contrast between extravagantly and tastefully than extravagantly and comfortably? I wonder. No idea if it has a name.

Comment: Make sense, thanks!

Comment: https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/summary has a taxonomy of commas. I think this would fall under "bracketing comma".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which type of comma is used here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95328/which-type-of-comma-is-used-here) (' Bracketing commas can appear as a pair to enclose an interruption in the middle of a sentence. They can also appear alone to separate an interruption at the start or end of a sentence. They serve to add more information to sentences that are complete.') Here, the noun/determiner phrase is extended.

Answer (score 0):

University of Sussex has a [Summary of Commas](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/summary) that describes four general types of commas. This use is an example of **bracketing comma**:

> Bracketing commas always come in pairs, unless one of them would come at the beginning or the end of the sentence, and they always set off a weak interruption which could in principle be removed from the sentence:

In your example it's not in a pair, but that's because the phrase being bracketed is at the end of the sentence. The bracketed phrase "but not extravagantly" can be sensibly removed from the sentence.